# Build "data" section of $.ajax method then add variable

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

This seems like a simple syntax issue but I'm stuck. I am building the data section for an $.ajax method (POST) like this

```
data = {var1:value1,var2:value2,var3:value3}
```

This work fine.

I need to add some more key/value pairs which have been previously created in a loop (and retrieved from HTML5 Session Storage), like this

```
moredata = 'var4:value4,var5:value5,var6:value6'
```

My question is how do I add the values from 'moredata' to 'data'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the jquery extend method to do this

```
var originalData = {val1: value1, val2: value2};

var moreData = {val3: value3, val4: value4, val1: newValue1}; // i did newValue1 on purpose see below

$.extend(originalData, moreData);  // this basically pushes the moreData into the originalData, it will also update any matching values to the new ones
```

so the final value will look like this

```
orignalData = {val1: newValue1, val2: value2, val3: value3, val4: value4};
```

hope this helps you can go [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) for more information on the jQuery extends api

**Updated answer to include code to convert the string into a json Object**

```
function convertBadJsonStringToGoodJsonObject(badString){
    // expected format will not work with other format
    //  'var4:value4,var5:value5,var6:value6'
    //  also assumes the the value4 and value5 VALUES are the "actual" string values of the key/value pair.  if not then they will need to be put in the string.

    var returnData = {};

    // first split on ,

    var keyValues = badString.split(",");

    for(var i = 0; i < keyValues.length; i++){
        // ok should be a list of items like this
        // 'var4:value4

        // now we need to split on the :
        var keyValuePair = keyValues[i];

        var pair = keyValuePair.split(":");
        if (pair.length === 2){
            var key = pair[0];
            var value = pair[1];

            // now convert this to a json object
            var stringifiedJson = '{"' + key + '":"' + value + '"}';
            // should look like this now 
            // '{"var4":"value4"}'

            try{
                var newProperJsonObject = JSON.parse(stringifiedJson);

                $.extend(returnData, newProperJsonObject);

            } catch (ex) {
                // something went wrong with the parse, perhaps the original format wasnt right.
            }
        } // else not a valid pair
    }

    return returnData;
}

var badString = 'var4:value4,var5:value5,var6:value6';

var goodObject = convertBadJsonStringToGoodJsonObject(badString);

console.log(goodObject);
```

A few things to explain about the answer above.  First, JSON format is a very specific format for data transport.  While javascript uses a lazy version of it for its uses, the JSON.parse expects the string to be in a "real" json format.  Which means the keys need to be surrounded by double-quotes.  In javascript you can define an object as {val: value1} and life is good.  But for for JSON.parse the string will need to be '{"val1":"value1"}'.  If you pass it '{val1:value1}'.  It will break and throw a javascript exception.  Which is why I have it surrounded in a try catch.

I made the function purposely verbose but feel free to ask questions on it.  Once your string object is properly converted the $.extend function will work as I explained earlier.

Comment: thanks - however 'moredata' is a string i.e moredata = 'var4:value4,var5:value5,var6:value6' how do i get it to moreData = {val3: value3, val4: value4, val1: newValue1} simply adding braces to the start and end of the string doesn't seem to work

Comment: I updated my answer to explain how to change the original string to a json object.

Answer (score 1):

You are certainly able to pass them as an array.

```
data = {var1:value1,var2:value2,var3:value3, arrVars:moredata}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data['var4'] = 'value4';
data['var5'] = 5;
data['var6'] = 6;
```

And so on

Answer (score 0):

i believe you will like to have the whole data section as one string so I suggest you join the two strings by concatenation. All you have to do is wait until the concatenation time before adding the start and end curly braces i.e. {}. See this

```
data = 'var1:value1,var2:value2,var3:value3'
moredata = 'var4:value4,var5:value5,var6:value6'
data = '{' + data + ',' + moredata + '}'
```

Comment: That seems promising however it doesn't seem to supply  $.ajax with correctly formatted data - Chrome Console shows the posted data as {var:value1,var2:value2} all on one line - when correctly formatted it should be var1:value1   var2:value2 with each pair on a new line